# How to check whether a number or not in array on structure in C

Tags: c, arrays

there's a structure of arrays like this.

```
typedef struct
{
    char mother [50];
    char father [50];
} family;

family divorce [100];
```

On this array, I input the number + char (length is random) like 123a 253vv 2145eee..., and I'd like to save only number to the another char array. What should I do?

Comment: Take a look at [sscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) and [sprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [isdigit()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isdigit.htm) to determine whether the character is a decimal digit or not. If the char is a digit, populate it in the array.

Another way, check `if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') arr[i++] = ch;`